# Android Studio says Resource Must Start With a Letter, but it does

Tags: android, merge, android-gradle-plugin

Error:Execution failed for task `:app:mergeDebugResources`.

> C:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\pullupapp\apptime\PullUp\app\src\debug\res\values\googlemapsapi.xml: Error: The resource name must start with a letter

and

> C:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\pullupapp\apptime\PullUp\app\src\debug\res\values\googlemapsapi.xml
>   Error:Error: The resource name must start with a letter

================================================================

Does that make any sense to you? As far as I can tell every step of that path does in fact start with a letter. But my project won't compile or successfully build the gradle as is. Can you help?

Comment: what is inside googlemapsapi.xml?

Comment: Package name:
    81:84:A4:4A:CA:22:92:F3:BF:07:4C:9A:06:7A:ED:96:DA:27:28:CE

    SHA-1 certificate fingerprint:
    81:84:A4:4A:CA:22:92:F3:BF:07:4C:9A:06:7A:ED:96:DA:27:28:CE

    Alternatively, follow the directions here:
    https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get-key

    Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
    string in this file.
    -->
    <string name=" [My actual key is in here]="preserve" translatable="false">YOUR_KEY_HERE</string>
</resources>

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write correctly the string resource. Check this :

```
 <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">YOUR_KEY_HERE</string>
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
     android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Comment: Oooh okay, so if I understand: Don't replace "google_maps_key", but do replace YOUR_KEY_HERE instead of both?

Comment: google_maps_key is a friendly string name that you use to get "Google maps key" anywhere in your Android project. For your case, you need to reference this from your Android Manifest

Comment: You nailed it! Thank you so much!